# How to set up a $(document).ready function inside a file loaded by $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, getscript

I'm trying to compartmentalize the code for a webpage to load code only when needed.  I have one javascript file included in the head section of my page.  The page has a button, which when clicked, brings a div to the foreground, then populates the div through the use of $.getScript.  The newly loaded content consists of two additional divs and ten buttons.  However, the buttons don't work.  Whether I put the $('#element').click() code on my main html page, in my primary javascript file or the newly loaded file, it doesn't work.  Do I have something incorrectly formatted or is this just something that will never work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Test");  /*     This works     */
        $('#slideButton1').click(function() {
                alert("Testing");     /*   This doesn't     */
        });
});
```

Buttons are generated by the following code:

```
function addGalleryButtons() {
        var sLabels = new Array("Aircraft","Avatars","BattleArmor","BattleMechs","Book Covers","Characters","Lego BattleTech","Maps","Naval Vessels","Vehicles");
        var leftIndent = 15;
        for(var i=0; i<sLabels.length; i++) {
                var slBtn = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id','slideButton'+i);
                slBtn.addClass('base shadowed rad3 gSlideButton');
                slBtn.html(sLabels[i]);
                var slb = { 'left' : leftIndent+'px' , 'opacity' : '0.7' };
                slBtn.css(slb);
                slBtn.attr('title','slideButton'+i);
                slBtn.appendTo('#gallerySlider');
                leftIndent = leftIndent + $('#slideButton'+i).width() + 12;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you bind to `$('#slideButton1')` it doesn't exist in the DOM. The solution is to bind to the `$('#gallerySlider')` element using the `on` method.

```
$('#gallerySlider').on( 'click', 'div', function( e ){
  console.log( $( this ), $( this ).attr( 'id' ) );
});
```

It might be a good idea to give class names to your divs and target them  that way.

```
$('#gallerySlider').on( 'click', '.myClassName', function( e ){ // etc
```

Comment: This worked quite well.  I took a quick look at jsFiddle and it was not immediately intuitive about how to set it up if I'm using multiple javascript files.  Doing some investigation of the .on() functionality and a bit of trial-and-error, the below works perfectly well for a mouseover/mouseout.  And it handles each of the ten buttons.

    $('#galleryWindow').on('mouseover', '#gallerySlider div', function() { $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 200); });
    $('#galleryWindow').on('mouseout', '#gallerySlider div', function() { $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 200); });

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it would be great if you could provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). You do not give information on the order of when those two functions are called.

However, I would have written this in a comment if I could, but due to my insufficient reputation, I just can't. So I'll attempt an approach to your solution here.

Unline czarchaic, I wouldn't use `on`. I'd use the `live` method. Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for additional information, parameter lists, and an example. There are some downsides to this though. Some people dislike this methodology because the `live` method does eat quite some performance. They prefer delegate because it limits the elements that have to be checked for events. Consider an article like [this](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html). I do not remember which article I've read though, but I assume the information is quite similar.

Comment: @czarchaic's method is superior. `live` is deprecated, and for good reason. You CAN reproduce the same effect by using `$(document).on(etc)` (this is exactly `live`); however, this means that every element in the document is a listener. Why not make only the closest *non-destroyed* ancestor the listener? It performs better and for those to whom it matters (not everyone, I admit!) it's also more elegant.

Comment: @GregPettit Well, it's been a while since I worked with jQuery. My current phase in my current project does not require JavaScript. I haven't used the `on` method yet. I did admit that `I'd use the live method`. If I could, I would have posted a fourth of my answer as a comment, but well... I'm below 50 rep. That's something that really annoys me about StackOverflow... Anyways, thanks for your comment. I'll check in on that as I finally proceed to the phase requiring JS. :D

Answer (score 0):

The events aren't being wired because those elements aren't in the DOM yet..  That's why your buttons don't work.  I can't help but think what you're really looking for is a way to load scripts on demand.  I can personally recommend [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). It's a JavaScript module loader that will do exactly what you're trying to do. It's pretty straight forward.  [Get started here.](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)  Email me if you need a push.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your event handlers in a function that gets called by the returned javascript you should be fine.
    function() addHandlers{$('#slideButton1').click(function() { }

Then in at the end of your returned javascript:
    addHandlers();